# lwIP telnet example?

Tags: c, telnet, serversocket, lwip

I'm doing some experiments with lwIP on a small, embedded device. There are some examples that come with lwIP but they do not help me. What I want to implement is a server (using wlIP) that accepts a connection, reads several commands, sends several answers to the connected client and closes only when the connection is interrupted or a special close-command is sent.

So somehow similar to a telnet-server.

Is there an example for lwIP available that demonstrates this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question - but I found it when looking for something similar!

If you look in the lwip contrib directory (http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/lwip/) there are some example applications - including a tcp (and udp) echo server.

You don't say what device you are using or whether or not you are using an RTOS, so it is hard to provide example code.  However, if you are not using an RTOS I would highly recommend you start!  My experience of using the lwip raw api (without an rtos) is that it is difficult to read data from the outside world (e.g. using interrupts) without things falling over.

HTH,

Alex